# VLC for Amazon Fire: Compile from source

Tags: android, vlc, vlc-android, amazon-fire-tv

Anyone know how to do this? I successfully compiled the changes I want into vlc-android but I cannot install it on the Fire stick. Some of the errors I got were for release: This package seems to be corrupted. Ok that's strange it works on the android TV emulator. I try the debug build and it gets past the corrupted error but it says the app is not for my TV. So I assume there are special steps involved to get everything set up so that android studio can compile for fire.

I would love some instructions on how to do this. Thank you

Comment: share your code and commands please, and logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue I was having was I needed to use adb to connect to the fire stick instead of downloading the file and trying to install that way.